# An object reference is required for non-static field, method or property Bot_MessageReceived how do I fix this error?

Tags: c#, bots

So I am trying to create a bot for Discord an online voice and chat program built for gamers and I get this error when debugging.

> Error CS0501  'Program.Bot_MessageReceived(object, MessageEventArgs)'
>   must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or
>   partial   ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\nate\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs

This is my code

```
using Discord;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiscordBotTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bot = new DiscordClient();

            bot.MessageReceived += Bot_MessageReceived;

            bot.Connect("natebot@natesbot.tk", "password");

            bot.Wait();
        }
        // This code is run everytime a message is received
        private void Bot_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} said: {1}", e.User.Name, e.Message.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error is on line 16 for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

```
 private static void Bot_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} said: {1}", e.User.Name, e.Message.Text);
 }
```

Comment: man now that makes me feel stupid I guess we all make mistakes here and there though. Thank you!